# update markers from JSON on google maps

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, google-maps

Django 1.8 and python 2.7. 
I am trying to update the location of a marker using jQuery and Ajax.

My json object has only one array:

```
[{"latitud": "55.75222", "ciudad": "Moscu", "longitud": "37.61556"}]
```

After initialize the map, I create this function in order to set the marker and also I used setTimeout to get the new marker position.

```
function setMarker(map) {

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/maps/car/gpspos/', function(userPos) {
        userLat = userPos["userPosView"][0].latitud;
        userLon = userPos["userPosView"][0].longitud;
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
        });
        marker.setMap(map)


        // A function that checks if the user has a new position and set marker there
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                (marker.getPosition());
            },5000);
        });
    });
}
```

The result is that I can not get the new position when a new latitud and longitud values are entered to the db. 
I would be grateful is somebody could help me

Comment: How are the lat / lon values entered in to the db?

Comment: For the moment I am entering then manually but in the future an application would send this values.

Answer (score 0):

Save the previous lat, long in a variable, and check it when you are asking again to the db.

```
var lat, lng;

function setMarker(map) {

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/maps/car/gpspos/', function(userPos) {
        userLat = userPos["userPosView"][0].latitud;
        userLon = userPos["userPosView"][0].longitud;
        if(lat == null){ lat = userLat; }
        if(lng == null){ lng = userLat; }
        if(userLat != lat && userLon != lng){
            lat = userLat;
            lng = userLong;

            //do stuff
            Console.log("lat lng changed");
        }
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
        });
        marker.setMap(map)
    });
}
```

I guess you are asking to db calling the setMarker method.

Comment: Yes i call the setMarker in my function initializeMap().

Comment: However I want to refresh the page every 5 seconds, and if a new position is entered the marker should be in the new position

Comment: Then the best aproach for that is using a DataLayer, using the map.data.loadGeoJson('http://..') method. Each element sent by an ajax method (created my the function) is rendered, if the element has the same id, the position is updated automatically.

Comment: Lets me explain it better. I have a django server with sqlite db. In the database I have many data such as the latitude and the longitude of a user. Then I make a query selecting the last latitude and longitud of the current user logedd in and I parse it as a JSON format.

Comment: In my Javascript I can initialize the google map and I can set a marker. But what I want is to check the JSON every 5 seconds in order to know the last position of my logged user

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using the data layer.

You can call the server with the setTime method:

```
var geoUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/maps/car/gpspos/';
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        map.data.loadGeoJson(geoUrl);
    },5000);
});
```

But you have to send the json from server in a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 2
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Dinagat Islands",
            "ciudad": "Moscu"
        }
    }
]
}
```

In the second call to the server, every feature is updated by its id, so the position will change if it have been changed in the server side.

You can also change the style with this method, which is called for every feature drawn. Or event you can get a property of the feature

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
  //getting property
  var ciudad = feature.getProperty('ciudad');

  //setting style for each feature
  return({
      icon: '//example.com/path/to/image.png',
      fillColor: 'green'
  });

});
```